# Trying to set up Cloud Firestore security rules using request.path

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-security, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I am struggling to get my head around some Firestore security concepts. I want to set up a rule based on the `request.path` property.

My rule is this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.path[0]=='appUsers';
    }
  }
}
```

...and I then use [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) to add a document like this...

```
this.myAngularFirestore.doc('/appUsers/'+this.auth.auth.currentUser.uid).set({name: this.auth.auth.currentUser.displayName})
      .then(()=>console.log('Added user'))
      .catch(err=>console.log('Could not add user:', err.message));
```

I thought this should be simple [based on the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/?authuser=0#properties) but all I ever get is the error - `Missing or insufficient permissions`.

I know I am logged in correctly and I know the query works if I open up the security with `allow read,write: if true;` so what am I not getting here?
Shouldn't `request.path[0]` evaluate to the string `appUsers` here and so allow the data to be written?

Any ideas gratefully accepted as I'm not finding these rules much fun to out together so far.

Cheers all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using the built-in path matcher version of this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /appUsers {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you really want to specify in the condition:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{pathSegment} {
      allow read, write: if pathSegment == "appUsers";
    }
  }
}
```

`request.path` is the full path (e.g. `/projects/<projectId>/databases/(default)/documents/appUsers`, which means you'd actually want `request.path[5]` (hence why we provide easier, more readable ways of doing this).

Edit (4/2/18): `request.path` supports both `List` and `Map` access:

- `List`: `request.path[5] == "appUsers"`
- `Map`: `request.path['pathSegment'] == "appUsers"`, though note that it only works on wildcarded (e.g. `{name}`) values

Comment: That makes good sense but it doesn't seem to work for me?? I have set up a new Firebase project and Firestore database, a new Angular project (using the CLI), installed and initialised AngularFire2 and simplified the query as much as I can but the only rule that allows me to write successfully is `match /{segment=**} {allow read, write;}`. I tried your examples but just get the same permissions error. Is there any method for debugging rules or seeing what is failing in a request?

Comment: So, I have no luck with `request.path` at all - fails no matter how I phrase it -
 but as you say it's not necessary here and your second example has sorted me out in the end. I feel like I've learned something here but I can't really explain what - things are just a bit clearer in my head so thank you :)

Comment: @MikeMcDonald request.path[n] is never working for me. I am trying to check weather the current user has same uid as the path by 'request.auth.uid==request.path[10]' where 10 is calculated in the same way as the example. I have even checked with position other than 10 but it is still not working. I also checked by adding '/' to 'request.auth.uid' at the beginning thinking that path might have '/' at beginning but it is still not working. What could be the problem ?

Comment: @KartikWatwani the short answer is that I'm dumb and I documented it improperly. We don't currently offer index lookups, but we're adding them now. I'll fix the docs (and he behavior) soon!

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Is there any alternative to accessing request path segments until index lookups are available? And is this feature slated for release yet?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald I want to update my app soon too. Minimum how long will it take before index look up come in because if it will take time I will have to add uid in the requested document instead ?

Comment: @MandisaW the current behavior pulls out named segments, so: `/{foo}/{bar}/{baz}` would allow for `request.path['foo'] == someValue`, but not `request.path[1] == someValue`. The code was just committed, so I expect it'll be in production with the next rollout (maybe next week?). I'll update the thread with info when it's ready.

Comment: Ok, list accessors for `request.path` should be live now!

Comment: @MikeMcDonald List index accessor confirmed working in production as of 4/18/2018, thanks! But I could use some clarification on the relationship between named path segments and `request.path` Map keys. Maybe a blog post on crafting Security Rules?

Answer (score 0):

Mike McDonald answerer helped me to create a rule that will allow read for all tables unless the collection name is inside an array of "hasReadRules" (the generic allow read statement was preventing me from overriding read rules for some tables because if you have an allow read true somewhere it will override any allow read false that you have in any other rule):

```
// allow read for all collection that are not in the hadReadRules array
match /{pathSegment}/{document=**} {
  allow read: if !(pathSegment in hasReadRules());
  allow write: if false;
}
// these collection will have their own read rules
function hasReadRules() {
    return ["calculations", "users", "push_notifications"];
}

// below is an example where i want to override the allow
//read rule for a single collection without having to create a read rule for every collection
// If we do this without using the hadReadRules approach it wont work, because the rule bellow will be override by the generic allow read in the first rule statement
match /calculations/{id} {
  allow read: if belongsTo(resource.data.user_uid);
}

function belongsTo(userId) {
    return request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```