# firestore - request.path is undefined in emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm setting up Firestore Security Rules to allow collection group queries using the recursive wildcard syntax.

My data looks like this:
`/providers/providerId/employeesPrivate/employeeId`

The security rule I have is this:

```
match /{path=**}/employeesPrivate/{employeeId} {
  allow read, write: if isAdminAtProvider(request.path[6]);
}
```

Where `request.path[6]` is supposed to correspond to the `providerId` document ID based on [this answer and comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275346/trying-to-set-up-cloud-firestore-security-rules-using-request-path)

For simplicity, let's assume that the `isAdminAtProvider` function is like this:

```
function isAdminAtProvider(providerId) {
  return providerId == 'test'
}
```

`request.path[6]` is making the emulator throw an error:

`Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: evaluation error at L207:29 for 'list' @ L207`

What's interesting is that if I put a `debug` into the rule like:

```
match /{path=**}/employeesPrivate/{employeeId} {
  allow read, write: if debug(request) && isAdminAtProvider(request.path[6]);
}
```

The logs show that request.path is `undefined`:

```
...
fields {
  key: "path"
  value {
    undefined {
    }
  }
}
...
```

I have 2 goals here:

- keep the wildcard syntax so that collection group queries work
- extract the providerId from the request path so I can verify authorization (without adding the providerId property redundantly into the document as a prop)

Comment: This could be related to [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1279). Perhaps the `n` position may be different in `request.path[n]` due to the emulator prefix. Have you tried to write it out directly - `/{foo}/{bar}/{baz}` would allow for `request.path['foo'] == someValue`, as mentioned in the other Stackoverflow post that you shared?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That GitHub issue seems to be about HTTP triggers in Cloud Functions. My issue is with Firestore security rules, so it seems unrelated, I saw it earlier too. Writing out the full path is not something I can do, as that will break collection group queries as I understand.

Comment: You're right, after having a second look, it's totally unrelated. But now, I see you're using version 2 for your security rules (works with collection group queries) and adding this `providerId` isn't an option for you (redundancy). You're recursive wildcard now matches any document in the `employeesPrivate` collection group. Have you tried simply using the `providerId` wildcard from the match section to write your condition, so `providerId == test'?